# .NET Logging Class Doesn't Write

Tags: c#, .net, logging, iostream, streamwriter

I just wrote a simple logging class for use among various threads, based on examples I found at MSDN and a few other sites. Problem is, it creates the file log file, but never actually writes anything to it (it writes to the console properly though).

```
public class Logger
{
    private static Logger instance;
    private Logger() { }
    private static StreamWriter writer;

    public static Logger GetInstance()
    {
        lock (typeof(Logger))
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Logger();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void OpenFile(String file)
    {
        // Open log file for writing and append to it
        writer = new StreamWriter(file, true);
    }

    public void LogMessage(String message)
    {
        string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss :: ");

        writer.WriteLine(dt + message);
        Console.WriteLine(dt + message);
    }

    public void LogError(String error)
    {
        string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss :: ");

        writer.WriteLine(dt + "ERROR: " + error);
        Console.WriteLine(dt + "ERROR: " + error);
    }
}
```

and I am doing the following in my Program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger log = Logger.GetInstance();
    log.OpenFile("app.log");

    log.LogMessage("Starting App...");
```

Comment: Not that it solves this problem, but I highly recommend logging to an interface, rather than a concrete class.  Or go with a logging library like NLog.  It is worth the small amount of time it takes to set up, because you will gain a lot of flexibility with very little up-front work.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a logging framework like log4net or NLog, too.

Comment: In my case I just need a very simple log file. Why is it recommended to use one of these instead?

Comment: NLog can write to a simple file. And it's tested. And it handles multithreading just fine. And if it crashes, it won't affect your code. It's fun to wind up your own logging class but I would never do this for production code. It's too easy to miss some file IO corner case and too easy to use an existing solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
writer.WriteLine(dt + message);
writer.Flush();
```

or when you declared the `writer` set [AutoFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) to true:

```
writer = new StreamWriter(file, true);
writer.AutoFlush = true;
```

**Edit:** Also since your class will access from multi-thread so you should use `lock` before writing to the stream because the `StreamWriter` instance is not thread safe, so:

```
private readonly object _writerLocker = new object();

lock (_writerLocker)
{
    writer.WriteLine(dt + "ERROR: " + error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in comment:  Why is it recommended to use one of these (Log4Net, NLog) instead?

- Because it's already debugged.
- Because you avoid nasty bugs such as the multithreading write access pointed to by Jalaal.
- Because the day your logging needs change (or you want to get rid of logging!), you don't even need to recompile your program: It's simply a matter of configuration in your app.config.
- Because once you have learned to use such a logging framework, you'll be able to re-use it very easily in other projects or contexts, which may have more advanced requirements.
- Because once you realize how powerful yet easy to use they are, you may want to add more powerful logging without the need to program it.

BTW, my +1 goes to [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).